# My openvpn clients connects to server with .ovpn+ca.crt files only

Tags: server, openvpn

I ask you if my clients connect to openvpn server through two files only: client.ovpn and ca.crt, Is this connection secure? Any security problems in this mechanism there? Is the connection encrypted?

**Knowing that:**

1. Clients can connect without any problems or warnings,
2. Openvpn client should connect to server though these four files: client.crt client.key ca.crt client.ovpn ,
3. client.ovpn as shown:

```
client
dev tun0
proto tcp
remote IP PORT
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
# cert client.crt
# key client.key
remote-cert-tls server
;tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
auth-user-pass pass
```

Server configuration:

```
port port 
proto tcp 
dev tun0 
ca ca.crt 
cert server.crt 
key server.key 
dh dh2048.pem 
server P.P.P.P 255.255.255.0 
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt 
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4" push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8" 
cipher AES-128-CBC 
comp-lzo 
persist-key persist-tun 
status openvpn-status.log verb 3 
client-cert-not-required 
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so login
```

Comment: What is the corresponding server configuration? Is the user prompted for a password?

Comment: @vidarlo  : The user is promoted for a password which saved in a file, the user has 3 files only(client.ovpn+ca.crt+pass) 

------- ** Server Configuration ** -------


port port
proto tcp
dev tun0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  
dh  dh2048.pem
server P.P.P.P 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
cipher AES-128-CBC  
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
client-cert-not-required
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so login

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include new information. As a sidenote, when a password is used, the connection is authenticated. Is this safe enough? It depends on the purpose of the VPN connection and what it protects. There is no fixed answer. In some instances a unencrypted, unauthenticated VPN may be all fine and dandy. In others, not so.

Comment: @vidarlo  Are the clients connection with server encrypted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the server configuration you have the following lines:

```
client-cert-not-required 
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so login
```

`client-cert-not-required` has the following description from `man openvpn`:

> Don't require client certificate, client will authenticate usingu sername/password only. Be aware that using this directive is less secure than requiring certificates from all clients.

The plugin requires authentication against PAM.

The data is encrypted when it transits the VPN. This is shown by the line `cipher AES-128-CBC`, which specifies which encryption to use. AES is generally regarded as secure.

If you consider this secure enough depends on what you are attempting to protect, and the quality of the passwords. There's no one-stop answer to this; you have to define the threats you find applicable, and what security is **acceptable**.

Maintaining a CA and distributing certificates may be more work than distributing passwords. This depends on your setup. It also makes it more difficult to setup VPN on a new computer, as you securely have to bring the relatively long key to that computer. The decreased security of password authentication may be a worthwhile trade off in this aspect.

TL;DR: It depends.

Comment: Can you explain which configurations must be added to authenticate clients using certificates from all clients. 
I want to allow more clients to use the unique certificate.

Comment: Remove the line `client-cert-not-required`.

Comment: Are client-cert-not-required allows many client to use the unique certificate?

Comment: If you remove the `client-cert-not-required` each client will need a certificate signed by the same CA as the servers certificate.